# Arraylist of bespoke objects using inheritance

Tags: c#, arraylist

In my app I retrieve 3 rows of data from my database, I loop through the rows of data to assign the data to my customer object, then add the customer to a customer collection:

```
// new customer object to fill in loop and assign to collection
tracker.Customer myCustomer = new tracker.Customer();

// new customer collection object to fill later
Tracker.customerCollection  myCustomerCollection = new trackerCustomerCollection();

foreach (System.Data.DataRow drRow in dsResults.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
  myCustomer.CustomerID = Item["CustomerID"];
  myCustomer.FKBandID = Convert.ToInt32(drRow["FKBandID"]);
  myCustomer.FKSectorID = Convert.ToInt32(drRow["FKSectorID"]); 
  myCustomer.CustomerName = Convert.ToString(drRow["CustomerName"]);
  myCustomer.CustomerAddress = Convert.ToString(drRow["CustomerAddress"]);
  myCustomer.CustomerPhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(drRow["CustomerPhoneNumber"]);

  myCustomerCollection.Add(myCustomer);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to use the populated `myCustomerCollection`, the 3 `Customer` objects within the collection are all identical. Each instance of `myCustomer` is different as I iterate through the loop, but they change once added to `myCustomerCollection`. each item will be the same as the last item added.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful, I have used this principle in VB.NET with no issues, but I'm now forced to use C# and having real trouble finding the source of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're creating 1 instance of your `Customer` object, and adding it to the list 3 times (modifying it each time you loop).

If you move your `new tracker.Customer()` inside the loop, you'll create 3 individual customer objects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. works a charm.

I had previously thought that by assigning myCustomers attributes with new values, it would have been like a new object each time it was added to the collection

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `tracker.Customer` in each iteration of the for loop instead of a single instance outside of the loop:

```
foreach (var drRow in dsResults.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
    // Create a brand new instance of a customer and set its properties
    var myCustomer = new tracker.Customer()
    {
        CustomerID = Item["CustomerID"];
        FKBandID = Convert.ToInt32(drRow["FKBandID"]);
        FKSectorID = Convert.ToInt32(drRow["FKSectorID"]); 
        CustomerName = Convert.ToString(drRow["CustomerName"]);
        CustomerAddress = Convert.ToString(drRow["CustomerAddress"]);
        CustomerPhoneNumber = Convert.ToString(drRow["CustomerPhoneNumber"])
    };
    // Add your new customer to the customer collection
    myCustomerCollection.Add(myCustomer);
}
```

What's happening right now is that your `myCustomerCollection` contains three references to the same `myCustomer` instance, because you aren't instantiating a `new` one for each record in your database. The values you're seeing now in `myCustomer` probably pertain to the last row of your data.

By creating a **new instance** in each iteration of the for loop, you will have three distinct `tracker.Customer` objects in your list.

This behavior would be exactly the same in VB.NET.